# Convert text-overflow: ellipsis text to "floating" view of full text

Tags: css, angular-material

I have an Angular/Material side panel containing label/input control pairs. An example is below pairing a label with a mat-slide-toggle:

```html
<div class="flex justify-between items-center">
  <span class="mat-slide-toggle-content">
 {{ 'StringReference' | translate }}
  </span>
  <mat-slide-toggle [ngModel]="booleanValue" (ngModelChange)="handleModelChange($event)" name="aToggle" color="primary">
  </mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

Since some of the label text could be long, particularly in translated versions, I'd like to have a "backup plan" maintaining the layout but still making the label text accessible. The ellipsis works fine when the label is too wide and text-overflow: ellipsis is set.

Maintaining access to the **whole** string is my problem. I'd like to "tooltip-ize" the label text, floating it above the neighbor control on hover **without relayout**, showing the whole string. I can change the text-overflow setting, of course, and generally stretch the label to fit, but this causes a relayout of the control, which I don't like. Since I have hundreds of such labels, I don't want an HTML or JavaScript solution with tooltips or similar.

Any CSS-only thoughts that might work?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the perfect answer as your code snippet wouldn't render here, but I imagine it's just a side pullout kind of thing.  Here's a potential, CSS-only solution that you could work with; I just used bootstrap columns to show cutoff and expansion:

**Concept**: Toggle styles on active state.

**Example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ellipsis-but-shown-on-active

The gruntwork would be in the two custom classes which I modeled for col-4 at a certain width:

```
.col-4-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.col-4-overflow:active {
    overflow: visible;
    text-overflow: inherit;
    background: cornsilk;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 66.66666666666666%;
    margin-right: -180px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You might be able to figure out a more elegant replacement for the margin-right and z-index values of the active state, I dunno. :)